# XSS: How is this safe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, xss

I have following code:

```
echo "<span title='{$_GET["t"]}'>Foo</span>";
```

Obviously, this code is not XSS-Save, but when I call following URLs, no JavaScript is executed:

1. `url?t=Foo" onclick="alert(1)"`
2. `url?t=<script>alert(1);</script>`

Is the browser doing some magic work here? Is there any attack vector?

Comment: in the first case you are not matching the closing single quote, in the second script would not execute inside a title attribute

Comment: Have you looked at the generated HTML? I don't think you're generating what you think you're generating.

Comment: `Is there any attack vector?` erm, yes - _everything_ about this. You are blindly trusting user input and putting it in executable environment with no change. There is nothing about this that can be deemed safe.

Comment: `url?t=Foo' onclick="alert(1)" i='`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why should it be? You'd be generating the following:

1. `<span title='Foo" onclick="alert(1)"'>Foo</span>`
2. `<span title='<script>alert(1)</script>'>Foo</span>`

Neither of which are valid html/javascript. The first one has mismatches in the quotes, so the tags are broken. The second one doesn't have javascript. it has a title attribute containing the characters `<`, `s`, `c`, etc... That's not javascript. It's just some TEXT that **LOOKS** like javascript.

To do XSS, whatever you inject **HAS** to produce valid code, otherwise it's just a syntax error for whatever environment you're injecting.

A working example would be:

```
http://example.com/script.php?t='><script>alert('1');</script><span+title='
```

which would generate

```
<span title=''><script>alert('1');</script><span title=''>Foo</span>
xxxxxxxxxxxxx0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Where `x` represents the original document, and `0` represents what you injected.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to test if this is vulnerable, you need to end the single quote and close the tag, *then* add your javascript. Something like the following:

```
?t=xss'><script>alert('hi')</script><span
```